# awk проверка поля на текст

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, awk

Нужно проверить является ли поле строки текстом или числом. Я побывал это: `if ($2 != /[0-9]/){...}else{...}`, но такая конструкция некорректно срабатывает и работает только блок else. Я только знакомлюсь с awk, поэтому не ругайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте оператор `!~`.  Пример:

```sh
$ more ./tmp.txt
1 aaaa
2 2222
3 c3c3
$ awk '{ print $2 !~ /^[0-9]+$/; }' ./tmp.txt 
1
0
1
$
```